# Import firebase analytics settings to another package

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Is there a way to import my firebase settings (Audienes and User properties) from my Android package to iOS package for the same project ?

I have tried to google it but nothing so far.

The reason I want to somehow automate it is I have like 30 audiences and 10 User properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. There is currently no way to do this. It's not a bad idea, though. I'll file it with the team as a feature request.

Comment: Can you please add the URL ? Can't find it

Comment: Well, it's internal, so there's no URL, but if you want to add your own request, feel free to do so at https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/